# Java get current working directory when double click .jar

Tags: java, jar, directory

I have a java application which uses the following line

```
new File(new File(".").getAbsolutePath())
```

When running the program from a terminal as:

```
~/Documents/Routes$ java -jar myApp.jar
```

The program correctly interprets the java line as folling

```
/home/user/Documents/Routes
```

This route is the working directory of the terminal. However if I double click the myApp.jar the result is a bit random

```
/home/user/Download/.
```

Which could be the cause that I am getting an incorrect "running" path ?

Comment: Is this a Linux system? Looks like it.

Comment: Possible duplicate question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file)

Comment: @Benson99 He knows how to get the path.  He wants to know why it's different depending on how he launches the application.

Comment: The content of that post (I thought, anyhow) was that some operating systems will resolve to the command line root rather than the actual jar file.

Comment: @KevinO I will look at the answer of your comment. It looks interesting because it differentiates between the running directory and the jar file location. Will provide feedback once tested